# Executando uma função alocada em um objeto a partir de uma comparação em for

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou construindo uma biblioteca para validar formulários(eu sei que existem inúmeras mas o meu caso é específico) e queria poder enviar para uma função um objeto com os campos e em seu subnível seus validadores. assim a partir de um comparativo, quando no objeto houver um validador ele execute a função referente a aquele validador. Assim:

```
var validador = {//verificador...
  notNull : function(i){return i!=0},
  maxLength : function(i,l){return i<=l},
  minLength : function(i,l){return i>=0}
}

obj = {//que envio para o validador, exemplo validando 2 campos(nome,telefone)
    nome : {
        notNull : [mensagem], 
        maxLength : [100,mensagem],
        minLength : [10,mensagem]
    },
    telefone : {
        maxLength : [12,mensagem],
        minLength : [8,mensagem]
  }
}

//checar se os campos estão certos...
function check(campos,obj){
  var c = campos;
  $.each(obj,function(i1,v1){
    $.each(validador, function(i2,v2){
      if(i1==validators[i2]){
       /* 
        * validator[i2](); ???
        * pela logica, se existe esse validador eu enviaria o valor(validador[0])
        * para a função e receberia o retorno dela em uma condicional, dizendo que
        * se a validação fosse 'false' que ele retornasse a a mensagem (validador[1])
        */
      };
    });
  });
};
```

alguém ai tem uma solução pra mim, to meio perdido em relação a o envio de dados e callback quando não sei qual função executar dentro de um objeto...

help

Comment: Estou um pouco perdido: o que é `mensagem` e o que é `campos`? podes dar um exemplo de como chamarias essa função? um jsFiddle é sempre excelenete.

Answer (score 0):

Retrabalhei seu código, comentando passo a passo. Também eliminei a dependência do jQuery, o código usa somente JavaScript puro. Espero que ajude.

```js
// Esta parte ficou quase igual
var validadores = {
    // O nome notNull não fazia sentido com a sua verificação, alterei
    // A função de trim não está disponível no IE8, se quiser suporte
    // use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Polyfill
    notEmpty : function(i){return i.trim() != ''},
    
    // Os métodos abaixo comparam o comprimento do valor passado, 
    // e não mais o próprio valor
    maxLength : function(i,l){return i.length <= l},
    minLength : function(i,l){return i.length >= l}
}

// Aqui só preenchi as mensagens e mudei o notNull para bater
// com a mudança que fiz acima.
// Estou considerando que as chaves nesse objeto correspondem
// aos IDs dos campos no seu formulário.
obj = {
    nome : {
        notEmpty : ["O nome não pode estar vazio"], 
        maxLength : [100, "O nome não pode ter mais que 100 caracteres"],
        minLength : [10, "O nome não pode ter menos de 10 caracteres"]
    },
    telefone : {
        maxLength : [12, "O telefone não pode ter mais que 12 caracteres"],
        minLength : [8, "O telefone não pode ter menos que 8 caracteres"]
    }
};


// Aqui eu explico a lógica passo a passo
function check(obj, validadores){

    var el, campo, valor, criterio, mensagem, funcao, argumentos;

    // Pega cada chave de campo no objeto
    for(campo in obj) {
    
        // O elemento do DOM correspondente ao campo
        el = document.getElementById(campo);
        
        // O valor do campo
        valor = el.value;
        
        // Loop nas definições dos critérios de validação de cada campo
        for(criterio in obj[campo]) {
            
            // pega a mensagem na array
            mensagem = obj[campo][criterio].slice(-1);
            
            // referência à função que será usada
            funcao = validadores[criterio];
            
            // prepara uma nova array para passar como argumentos da função;
            // essa array é o valor do campo e os dados de validação, exceto mensagem
            argumentos = [valor].concat(obj[campo][criterio].slice(0, -1));
            
            // invoca a função com os argumentos que preparamos. se ela retornar
            // false, alerta a mensagem e interrompe a validação
            if(!funcao.apply(null, argumentos)) {
                alert(mensagem);
                
                // Interrompe a checagem se algo não validar
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Passou em todas as validações
    return true;
};

// Clique no botão
document.getElementById('validar').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(!check(obj, validadores)) {
        alert('NÃO VALIDOU');  
    } else {
        alert('VALIDOU')  
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="nome">
<input id="telefone">
<button type="button" id="validar">Validar</button>
```

Comment: No método notEmpty o ideal seria fazer um trim na String, para limpar campos vazios. :)

Comment: Coloquei o `trim` + o aviso de IE9+